# sql server inserts not working in release mode

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a C# desktop app that inserts rows into a sql server database.  I noticed that if I build in Release mode, the rows do not appear in the database.  But if I build in Debug mode, it works fine.  What could be causing this?

Comment: You can still debug a release-mode build, you know.. Have you investigated at all?

Comment: Do you have any logging in your application?

Comment: Is the config for release and debug different (maybe release is pointing to a different Database, thus it is working you just are looking at the wrong DB)

Comment: No the connection string is being supplied by the user... I'm supplying the same one in both modes

Comment: Can you show some code? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Blorgbeard for pointing out that I can debug in release mode!  When I switched to release mode and tried to set a breakpoint, I noticed that the code to execute the Insert was "grayed out" in Visual Studio!  The code was:

```
Debug.Assert(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
```

Apparently Debug.Assert gets skipped in Release mode.

I fixed it by changing it to:

```
var nRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Debug.Assert(nRows == 1)
```

**EDIT:**

The above solution is not ideal because, although it now works in release mode, it only checks the return code in Debug mode.  A better version is:

```
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() != 1)
    throw new ApplicationException("sql statement failed");
```